# I am having a problem with Flutter/Dart Async code execution, as in how does it work

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter we use async await and Future, can someone explain that if we don't use another thread (which we can't in dart) and run the job on main UIThread only won't the app become choppy because even if we are waiting for the job to execute it will ultimately execute on UIThread only.
I somewhere read about isolates also. But cannot paint the exact picture. If someone can explain in detail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you missed something when it comes to asynchronous methods in Dart.
Dart is a single-threaded programming language, Java or C# are multi-threaded programming languages, forget `async` as a new thread, it doesn't happen in Dart.

As a rule, everything you do in Dart will start in UI-Thread.
In Flutter, the main UI thread is used for rendering the interface and responding to user inputs. Running heavy computations or long-running tasks on this thread can lead to a choppy app experience because the UI would be blocked. To address this issue, Dart provides asynchronous programming features like async/await, Future, and Isolates.

Async/await are constructs in Dart that allow you to write non-blocking code. When you mark a function as async, you're indicating that the function can run asynchronous operations. Inside an async function, you can use the 'await' keyword before any asynchronous operation. This operation will return a Future object, which represents a potential value that will be available at some point in the future. You can use 'then()' too to achieve the same, but using callbacks.

In a synchronous language, you would probably have this:

```
String user = new Database.fetch(David);
String personalData = new Database.fetch(user);
```

You will receive David's data in user, and after that, you will receive your data. This will block everything you are doing until the result is ready. This can cause freezes and performance issues.

In multi-threaded languages, you can create a new thread, and delegate a task to it, this will make the execution in simultaneous threads (which doesn't happen with dart or javascript, since they are single thread).

If you do this at Dart or javascript

```
String user = new Database.fetch(David);
String personalData = new Database.fetch(user);
// (Update note: when I wrote this answer dart still used "new",
// nowadays you don't need and shouldn't use it, in javascript yes.)
```

user will be null in personalData, because the fetch event is a Future.

How to solve this in Dart?

```
String user = await Database.fetch(David);
String personalData = await Database.fetch(user);
```

You've told dart that you're going to wait for the result of `fetch` asynchronously.

You can use callbacks to achieve the same with `then`, although I personally don't like that.

```
Database.fetch(David).then((user){
  Database.fetch(user).then((personal){
    String personalData = personal;
  });
});
```

So using await will make dart behave like multithreaded languages with amazing performance, right? **WRONG!!!!**, even though dart is running this asynchronously, which is better than blocking sync, you're still running this in the MAIN THREAD! Your UI can still crash if you overload it with heavy tasks!
Imagine that you have billions of data in that database, this heavy task will probably cause the animations on your screen to freeze, and you will see a jank in the user's UI, for that purpose isolates were invented.

Dart Isolates give you a way to perform a multi-threading like system. They have their own separate heaps(memory), and run the code in the background, similar to Threads of multi-threaded languages. I could explain how isolates work, but it would make this response very long, and the goal is just to differentiate asynchronous from multi-threaded methods.

A simple way to solve the problem above using isolates in Flutter would be using `compute`.

Compute was created to facilitate the creation of isolates, you just pass the function and the data that this function will execute, and that's it!
Important to remember that compute is a Future, so you have to use `await` or `then` to get its result.

In our example, we could create a new thread and get its result when we finish by just calling compute like this:

```
String user = await compute(Database.fetch,David);
String personalData = await compute(Database.fetch,user);
```

Very simple, isn't it?

In summary:
Everything that waits some time to be completed, in Dart is called a "Future".
To wait for the result of a future to be assigned to a variable, use `await` or `then`.
The asynchronous methods (`await` and `then`) can be used to obtain a result from a Future, and are executed ON THE MAIN THREAD because Dart is single-thread.
If you want to run any function on a new thread, you can create an isolate. Flutter offers an easy-to-use isolate wrapper called `compute`, where you only need to pass one method that will be processed and the data that will be processed, and it will return its result in the future.

- NOTE: if you are going to use compute make sure you are using a static or top-level method (see that in the example I used Database.fetch it was no accident if you need to call Database().fetch or need to create an instance of it, means it is not a static method and will not work with isolates).

Okay, so if dart provides isolates, shouldn't it be considered multithreaded?
Well, Dart provides a way to create concurrent computations using isolates, but it's important to note that isolates in Dart are not the same as threads in other programming languages.
Isolates != threads

In Dart, each isolate has its own heap of memory and communication between isolates takes place through message passing, unlike the shared memory model used in traditional multithreading. This means that isolates can run independently of each other and don't share mutable state, which can help avoid some of the concurrency issues that can arise in multithreaded programs (and can be a headache on occasions when you want to share a state among isolates)

So while Dart may not be strictly a multithreaded language, it does provide a powerful concurrency model that can help you create scalable and efficient applications, which doesn't make it a multithreaded language, because it doesn't actually have multithreading, it has multisolates, which, although they may behave in a similar way, have their peculiarities.

English is not my first language, but I hope I helped differentiate between multi-threaded asynchronous programming from single-threaded asynchronous programming.

Comment: This pretty much solves my query. Apart from this I just wanted to ask, is using isolate and compute a better approach to complete tasks as they act just like multithreaded code snippets?

Comment: The Spawn of the isolates takes some time to start. Usually 1 to 3 seconds. I recommend using isolates only for really heavy tasks or those that directly influence the fluidity of the UI.
Make your application without isolates, if you check a jank on a given task, I just replace function(anything) with compute(function, anything). In multithreaded language, the more threads the better, in singlethread, use them only when necessary.

Comment: Hey, @jonatasBorges. The notion of the dart being a single-threaded language is still unclear to me. If we can spawn a new thread using isolates, doesn't that make Dart a multithreaded language? Or am I misconceiving?

Comment: @hardik9850 Your question is a very good one! I updated the answer to mention it because it didn't fit in the comment, but in short, dart is not multithreaded because isolates are different from threads, they don't share the same state and have their own heap of memory.

Comment: Got it. Since the isolate can't share the state with other isolates directly and manages a separate heap, this principle is different from what we know about the green threads "Threads share resources with one another within the process they belong to" We are stamping Dart as a single-threaded language. @jonatasBorges did I put it right?

Comment: Nicely explained. Gr8!