# Why getting the Instance of SharedPreferences is an async function? Is it a good practice to cache the instance?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I wonder why is `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` an `async` function?! I want to cache the instance in a static variable and use it to store settings data without having to use `await` or `SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(...)`, but if they made it `async`, it should be for a good reason, any ideas?

Comment: I searched about dart async, and I found this answer that may help you figure your problem out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033892/i-am-having-a-problem-with-flutter-dart-async-code-execution-as-in-how-does-it

Comment: It is async because operations with memory takes time and in some device it would be longer than others.

Comment: i agree with @MohammedAlfateh , it would take some time to compute and check the data , so it needs to await and get it ,if you don't assign it as async function it will not take data and returns null , because it has no time to take data

Comment: @Teddichiiwa thanks for the link it's very informative.

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh I didn't know getInstance() actually fetch all stored data, this actually makes a huge difference

Comment: Yeah, but even if the stored data was small there some memory types work faster than others and also if there another operation doing an IO operation with the memory in the same time it would take longer to get the getInstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences.getInstance()` actually fetches the data and does not **only** provide a reference to a SharedPreferences's instance

based on the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart)

```
  static Future<SharedPreferences> getInstance() async {
    if (_completer == null) {
      _completer = Completer<SharedPreferences>();
      try {
        final Map<String, Object> preferencesMap =
            await _getSharedPreferencesMap();
        _completer.complete(SharedPreferences._(preferencesMap));
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        // If there's an error, explicitly return the future with an error.
        // then set the completer to null so we can retry.
        _completer.completeError(e);
        final Future<SharedPreferences> sharedPrefsFuture = _completer.future;
        _completer = null;
        return sharedPrefsFuture;
      }
    }
    return _completer.future;
  }
```

and

```
  static Future<Map<String, Object>> _getSharedPreferencesMap() async {
    final Map<String, Object> fromSystem = await _store.getAll();
    assert(fromSystem != null);
    // Strip the flutter. prefix from the returned preferences.
    final Map<String, Object> preferencesMap = <String, Object>{};
    for (String key in fromSystem.keys) {
      assert(key.startsWith(_prefix));
      preferencesMap[key.substring(_prefix.length)] = fromSystem[key];
    }
    return preferencesMap;
  }
```

I don't know if this was trivial, but it wasn't for me, I thought data are being fetched only on `get functions`.